# Wordpress get only posts with matching title not content

Tags: wordpress

Currently with this code below, I get posts whose title or description contains search keyword. How do I change it, so I only get posts whose title contains search keyword.

```
$search_keyword = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['query'] );

        $ordering_args = $woocommerce->query->get_catalog_ordering_args( 'title', 'asc' );
        $suggestions   = array();

        $args = array(
            's'                   => apply_filters( 'yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_search_query', $search_keyword ),
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'orderby'             => $ordering_args['orderby'],
            'order'               => $ordering_args['order'],
            'posts_per_page'      => apply_filters( 'yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_posts_per_page', get_option( 'yith_wcas_posts_per_page' ) ),
            'meta_query'          => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => '_visibility',
                    'value'   => array( 'search', 'visible' ),
                    'compare' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );

        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['product_cat'] ) ) {
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $_REQUEST['product_cat']
                ) );
        }

        $products = get_posts( $args );
```

I was trying to add one more query but only make it worse.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/11826/11704

Comment: @cale_b thank you this helped